# Difficulty converting html page with CSS and images to PDF in Django

Tags: html, django, pdf

I am trying to convert an HTML page which uses quite the bootstrap and styling. I tried everything from reportlab to weasyprint to xhtml2pdf and nothing works! I did not find anything online to help me do this simple task. I even tried looking for paid APIs that do this kind of jobs. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: "I am trying to convert an HTML page which uses quite the bootstrap and styling", what are you trying to convert an HTML page in?

Comment: It's in the title: PDF

Comment: do you want one specific page, or do you want to automate this process ?

Answer (score 1):

A guide to using an HTML template to create a PDF via a render_to_pdf utility function.

1. Open your Django project or create a blank one
2. Install xhtml2pdf docs:

Using Python 3

```
pip install --pre xhtml2pdf
```

Using Python 2

```
pip install xhtml2pdf
```

2. Add a utils.py module to your project:
3. Write the render_to_pdf function:

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

4. Create html template such as invoice.html in templates/pdf Recommended to use internal/inline stylesheets :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-weight: 200;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .header {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: 100;
                text-align: center;
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .title {
                font-size: 22px;
                font-weight: 100;
               /* text-align: right;*/
               padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;  
            }
            .title span {
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .details {
                padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
                text-align: left !important;
                /*margin-left: 40%;*/
            }
            .hrItem {
                border: none;
                height: 1px;
                /* Set the hr color */
                color: #333; /* old IE */
                background-color: #fff; /* Modern Browsers */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <div class='header'>
                <p class='title'>Invoice # </p>
            </div>
        <div>
        <div class='details'>
            Bill to: <br/>
            Amount:  <br/>
            Date: 
            <hr class='hrItem' />
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

5. Use in a view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

from yourproject.utils import render_to_pdf #created in step 4

class GeneratePdf(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {
             'today': datetime.date.today(), 
             'amount': 39.99,
            'customer_name': 'Cooper Mann',
            'order_id': 1233434,
        }
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

6. Force PDF Download:

```
class GeneratePDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = get_template('invoice.html')
        context = {
            "invoice_id": 123,
            "customer_name": "John Cooper",
            "amount": 1399.99,
            "today": "Today",
        }
        html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('invoice.html', context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("12341231")
            content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            download = request.GET.get("download")
            if download:
                content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

Comment: Is there a way we can use it without inline or internal CSS? Like using bootstrap for example?

Comment: Im not sure, you would have to do some more research on this. What i have posted is what i would recommend doing.

Comment: I haven't done this but i also don't use internal css but i only know how to do it with internal.

Comment: What if you're using a bootstrap template with a lot of styling that uses Sass and more than 70 000 lines of CSS what would you do?

Comment: Like i said, you would have to use an external file for your style. However i do not know how to convert files by doing it this way so you would have to do your own research